# pandas reading a text file generated from dataframe.to_string

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file which contains this table:

```
                   Ion  TheoWavelength         Blended_Set  
Line_Label                                                                                                                                             
H1_4340A    Hgamma_5_2        4340.471                None
He1_4472A     HeI_4471        4471.479                None
He2_4686A    HeII_4686        4685.710                None
Ar4_4711A       [ArIV]        4711.000                None
Ar4_4740A       [ArIV]        4740.000                None
H1_4861A     Hbeta_4_2        4862.683                None
```

This table has been generated from a pandas dataframe using dataframe.to_string and then saving the unicode variable.

I want to create a dataframe from this file using the pandas functions:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_table_file.txt', delim_whitespace = True, header = 0, index_col = 0)
```

However I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
    df = pd.read_csv(table, delim_whitespace = True, header = 0, index_col = 0)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 325, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/home/user/anaconda/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 815, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/user/anaconda/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1314, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 805, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:8748)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 827, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:9003)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 881, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9731)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 868, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:9602)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1865, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:23325)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4
```

I daresay it is caused due to the name of the index columns name in its own row.

Is there anyway to avoid this problem or to export the table without including this label?

P.S. I tried to use dataframe.to_csv table but as far as I known it does not allow you to play with the tables column formats if they have different dtypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [HDF5](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#hdfstore) format in this case - it'll take care of your index.

Beside that it's much faster compared to CSV, you can conditionally select data (like using SQL DB), it supports compression, etc.

Demo:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                   Ion  TheoWavelength Blended_Set
Line_Label
H1_4340A    Hgamma_5_2        4340.471        None
He1_4472A     HeI_4471        4471.479        None
He2_4686A    HeII_4686        4685.710        None
Ar4_4711A       [ArIV]        4711.000        None
Ar4_4740A       [ArIV]        4740.000        None
H1_4861A     Hbeta_4_2        4862.683        None

In [3]: df.to_hdf('d:/temp/myhdf.h5', 'df', format='t', data_columns=True)

In [4]: x = pd.read_hdf('d:/temp/myhdf.h5', 'df')

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
                   Ion  TheoWavelength Blended_Set
Line_Label
H1_4340A    Hgamma_5_2        4340.471        None
He1_4472A     HeI_4471        4471.479        None
He2_4686A    HeII_4686        4685.710        None
Ar4_4711A       [ArIV]        4711.000        None
Ar4_4740A       [ArIV]        4740.000        None
H1_4861A     Hbeta_4_2        4862.683        None
```

you can even query your HDF5 file, like a SQL DB:

```
In [20]: x2 = pd.read_hdf('d:/temp/myhdf.h5', 'df', where="TheoWavelength > 4500 and Ion == '[ArIV]'")

In [21]: x2
Out[21]:
               Ion  TheoWavelength Blended_Set
Line_Label
Ar4_4711A   [ArIV]          4711.0        None
Ar4_4740A   [ArIV]          4740.0        None
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It is very interesting the SQL functionality and it works nicely... However, for this case it must be a text file. I managed to make it work adding as comment in "read_csv" any row which starts with "L" (which is not an issue in this data). I have tried to use ignore_rows but it does not work if you set the columns index... that's weird...

Answer (score 2):

Consider Python's built-in `StringIO`, method of the `io` module as of Python 3 (`StringIO` as its own module in Python 2) to read text from a scalar string. Call it inside a pandas's `read_table()` and then manipulate the first lines of string content for headers:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''
                   Ion  TheoWavelength         Blended_Set
Line_Label
H1_4340A    Hgamma_5_2        4340.471                None
He1_4472A     HeI_4471        4471.479                None
He2_4686A    HeII_4686        4685.710                None
Ar4_4711A       [ArIV]        4711.000                None
Ar4_4740A       [ArIV]        4740.000                None
H1_4861A     Hbeta_4_2        4862.683                None
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\s+", header=None, skiprows=3, index_col=0)

headers = [item for line in data.split('\n')[0:3] for item in line.split()][0:4]
df.columns = headers[0:3]
df.index.name = headers[3]
```

In case you need to read from file, use `read_table` to read from file, and then read the text file to extract headers:

```
df = pd.read_table("DataframeString.txt", sep="\s+", header=None, skiprows=3, index_col=0)

data = []
with open("DataframeToString.txt", 'r') as f:
    data.append(f.read().split())

df.index.name = data[0][3]
df.columns = data[0][0:3]

print(df)
#                    Ion  TheoWavelength Blended_Set
# Line_Label                                        
# H1_4340A    Hgamma_5_2        4340.471        None
# He1_4472A     HeI_4471        4471.479        None
# He2_4686A    HeII_4686        4685.710        None
# vAr4_4711A      [ArIV]        4711.000        None
# Ar4_4740A       [ArIV]        4740.000        None
# H1_4861A     Hbeta_4_2        4862.683        None
```

Comment: Thank you very much of the reply but one question: If you have the "data" in a text file do you need to open the file twice (with readlines for example) or it can be done directly?